# TabLayout onTabSelected is not called if I select Tab programatically, but UI is changing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I want to implement simple `TabLayout` with 2 `Tabs`. But I noticed if I select tab programmatically, it will not trigger `onTabSelected,` only if I tap on it in UI.

Any suggestions how to trigger it?

```
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
                override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                    lastSelected = tab.position
                    startFragment()
                }

                override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
                override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
            })


tabs.getTabAt(0)?.select()
```

Comment: I select index 1 on tab layout programmatically and not call tab selected listener too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `tabs.getTabAt(0)?.select()` If your tab already select 0 it means `onTabSelected` is not called, it will be call `onTabReselected`. Common mistake when you call `tabs.addTab()` or using XML to setup `TabItem` it already select first tab you init. To fix it you should `addTab(tab, false)` it will be work like you want.

Comment: Adding same functionality to onTabReselected worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well.
You can us `View.performClick()` to make it works.

Comment: I cant. Tab is not View. It is not extending View class so I does not have this function available

Comment: Also tried `tabs.getChildAt(0)?.performClick()` which is returning some View, but it is not connected to listener at all.

Comment: Sorry,I think it is a TableLayout,not a TabLayout. I aways us the TableLayout or make the same function with RadioGroup+RadioButton or CheckBox,there may be so easy and function is the same with it